# Failed call to cuInit CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED (Device mapping: no known devices) Tensorflow-gpu 1.2.1

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I have 2 GPU's but not able to utilize via tensorflow-GPU, could anyone help to figure it out the issue.

**Versions:**

- Tensorflow GPU 1.2.1
- Cudnn 6.0.21
- Cuda 10.0 (toolkit)

  `import tensorflow as tf
   a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
   b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
   c = tf.matmul(a, b)
   with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
     print (sess.run(c))`

### Warning/Error message:

```
2018-11-09 12:06:42.827220: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:406] **failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED**
2018-11-09 12:06:42.827292: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:158] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: ca47dppaia001
2018-11-09 12:06:42.827309: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:165] hostname: ca47dppaia001
2018-11-09 12:06:42.827370: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:189] libcuda reported version is: 410.72.0
2018-11-09 12:06:42.827419: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:369] driver version file contents: """NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX ppc64le Kernel Module  410.72  Wed Oct 17 20:19:50 CDT 2018
GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC)
"""
2018-11-09 12:06:42.827457: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:193] kernel reported version is: 410.72.0
2018-11-09 12:06:42.827471: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:300] kernel version seems to match DSO: 410.72.0
**Device mapping: no known devices.**
2018-11-09 12:06:42.871454: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:265] Device mapping:
```

---

Comment: did you validate your CUDA 8.0 install?

Comment: Not able to execute "nvcc -V" but able to locate version.txt (tensorflow) [srcAI9@ca47dppaia001 cuda]$ ls
bin  extras   lib64      libnvvp  nsightee_plugins  nvvm    samples  targets  version.txt
doc  include  libnsight  LICENSE  nvml              README  share    tools
(tensorflow) [srcAI9@ca47dppaia001 cuda]$ version.txt
-bash: version.txt: command not found
(tensorflow) [srcAI9@ca47dppaia001 cuda]$ cat version.txt
**CUDA Version 10.0.130**

Comment: Your CUDA is not installed correctly.

Comment: When installing tensorflow-gpu, it does all the dependencies or something else do i need to do?

Comment: still failing with same issue but now i am able to get the CUDA version by setting the environment variable and executing $ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:10:00_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

Comment: well your cuda version is showing CUDA 10, not the CUDA 8 that you claimed in your question.